# Dynamically naming top level object key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign a socket to specific user's ID's and appear to be stuck, I have the following code for example,

```js
let user_list = {}

let socket = {}
socket[456] = "I am a socket"

user_list[123] = {...user_list, socket }
console.log(user_list)
```

I am trying to get the following result:

```
{
  "123": {
    "456": "I am a socket"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the spread operator with the `socket` object as well:

```js
let user_list = {}

let socket = {}
socket[456] = "I am a socket"

user_list[123] = {...user_list, ...socket}
console.log(user_list)
```

Comment: This one was selected because it does not overwrite the `user_list[123]` object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assign `user_list` to itself, see the change below:

```js
let user_list = {}

let socket = {}
socket[456] = "I am a socket"
// The only change is here:
user_list[123] = {...socket}
console.log(user_list)
```